# Shoppingcart synchronization with products in db

Tags: c#, shopping-cart

I have created a shoppingcart (C#) which is exclusively tied to the users session and stored in this as well, no problems here.

Whenever a user is putting an item in the cart, I have a property in the products db "reserved" which is added one, and as well "instock" is subtracted one. This helps me keeping track of stock size and product availability.

BUT in case user is not fulfilling the order, especially when browser is closed with a full shoppingcart, I need to clean up the products db, which is moving items from "reserved" back to "instock".

As I cannot detect browserclose, which annoyes me heavily, how can I get around this problem with maintaining products db in a clean and proper manner?

Any thoughts on this architecure issue, or am I missing something "best practice"?

Regards Finn.

Comment: Thanx Carlos for your comment. Yes I know I can do a job, but I want my solution to be as simple as possible. Might even think of a version of my shop which is without db. I'm thinking about going the hard way of making a cross browser library which can detect browser close with all its different events, if it is possible. I do not know this at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of stuff I would build a sql job based on time.

I would give the user X minutes to complete the purchase. If it is not completed
the sql job will delete that uncompleted register.

You can use the sql Agent to easily create job tasks

[**Sql Jobs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186273.aspx)